# In $100$ set of $10$ tosses of a coin, the number of cases you expect $7$ head and $3$ tail is.

Tags: probability

In $100$ set of $10$ tosses of a coin, the number of cases you expect $7$ head and $3$ tail is?

Comment: I tossed 100 coins and got 7 heads and 3 tails 0 times. now why don't you show us some of your work

Comment: What kind of work you want to see

Comment: @Rishab what have you tried to solve the problem? If you're absolutely stuck, then at least say what you've tried and doesn't work.

Comment: Well, where are you stuck? If you are not sure where to begin, try thinking about the probability of getting 7 heads and 3 tails in a single trial of 10 coin tosses.\

Comment: I have no idea of above problem if you can please provide me the solution

Answer (score 3):

Based on the description, I understand that you toss a coin ten times to see if you get $7$ heads and $3$ tails. Repeat this experiment $99$ more times.

The probability of getting $7$ heads and $3$ tails is $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{10}\times\dbinom{10}{7} $ if you flip a coin $10$ times. Your expected number after $100$ sets is just the previous number times $100$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the probability of getting $7$ heads out of $10$ implies that the remaining $3$ tosses were tails. The probability of getting $7$ heads out of $10$ tosses is given by the following binomial distribution:

$$
\frac{10!}{7!\times(10-7)!}\times0.5^{7}\times0.5^{10-7}=\frac{15}{128}
$$

After that, just multiply the probability by $100$, since the probabilities of each set of $10$ coin tosses are independent. Rounded to the nearest integer this leaves you with $11$ out of $100$ results in which you obtain $7$ out of $10$ heads.